# How to render previous page after jQuery post in Django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, url

I'm building a site that connects topics to questions to answers. Each question is associated with a topic, each answer a question, and so on. On the home page, I click on a topic, and it takes me to a dynamic URL based on the topic_id.

```
url(r'^(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', 'questions'),
```

When I add a question, the jQuery lightbox renders this URL in a pop up

```
url(r'^(?P<topic_id>\d+)/add_question/$', 'add_question'),
```

Once I submit the question, it goes through add_question.html

```
#add_question.html    
<div class="questionPopupForm">
    <h5><div class="questionPopupTitle"> Add Question</div></h5>
    <form action = "/home/{{ form.topic.id }}/add_question/" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.as_p }}</p>
        <p><div class="addQuestionButton"><input type = "submit" value = "Ask Question"     class="btn btn-success" /></div></p>
        <input type = "hidden" name = "next" value = "{{ next|escape }}" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Once I Submit, the Action then takes me to /home/{{ form.topic.id }}/add_question, which is the URL above, linking to the add_question view.

```
#views.py
def add_question(request, topic_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(user = request.user)
            question.topic = Topic.objects.get(pk = topic_id)
            question.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        form.q_author = request.user
        form.movie = Topic.objects.get(pk = topic_id)
    return render_to_response("qanda/add_question.html", {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Now right now, it takes me home with the return HttpResponeRedirect('/home/'). What I would like to do is redirect the user back to the same page, but there is a variable in the URL (/{{ topic.id }}/), but HttpResponseRedirect doesn't let me put a variable into it. How do I get back to the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpResponseRedirect requires a string (URL in this case), but you can construct it on the fly.  For example:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s/" % topic.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put a variable in the `HttpResponseRedirect`, but as a string, like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s/" % topic_id)
```

Also, try using the url alias using reverse:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('questions', topic_id=topic_id))
```

Or the Django shortcut `redirect()`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('questions', topic_id=topic_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

could you please try this?

```
#views.py
def add_question(request, topic_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(user = request.user)
            question.topic = Topic.objects.get(pk = topic_id)
            question.save()
            url = "/home/%s"%(str(topic_id))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        form.q_author = request.user
        form.movie = Topic.objects.get(pk = topic_id)
    return render_to_response("qanda/add_question.html", {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```